# Zend sessions not storing

Tags: session, zend-framework, configuration

I have problem sessions not storing.

In `applications.ini` I have:

```
session.save_path = APPLICATION_PATH "/data/sessions"
session.use_only_cookies = true
session.remember_me_seconds = 864000
session.gc_maxlifetime = 864000
session.cookie_lifetime = 864000
```

In **Bootstrap.php**

```
protected function _initSession(){
        Zend_Session::start();
        $session = new Zend_Session_Namespace();
        Zend_Registry::set("session",$session);

    }
```

In `login controller` in constructor I have:

```
$this->session = Zend_Registry::get ( 'session' );
```

I try save session:

```
var_dump(Zend_Session::rememberMe(864000));
```

but this return me `NULL`

In `sub.domain.com/data/sessions` also nothing storing

P.S `/data/sessions` have permissins 777

Where can be problem, If I try open `sub.domain.com/data/sessions/` I get Internal server error